# Django 3.0 images: Unable to display images in template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

#### I have model named Book in models.py file.

#### And based on this model, a view has been created to display images as products.

#### Which renders books(products) on shop.html template.

#### Problem is that i am unable to get their cover images which are saved across each publishers id who is seller of those books.

**This is code of shop.html (in which i am trying to display image).**

```
            <div class="container mt-4">
            <div class="row">
                {% for b in books|slice:":10" %}
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
                        <div class="book-card">
                            <div class="book-card__book-front">
                                <img src={{MEDIA_URL}}{{b.cover.url}} alt="book-image">
                            </div>      
                        </div>
                                <div class="book-card__title">
                                    {{ b.title }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
```

**This is the model in which i am putting covers of books against publisher's ids (names)**

```
def book_cover_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join(
    "covers", instance.publisher.user.username,  str(
        instance.pk) + '.' + filename.split('.')[-1]
)

class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=255)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name='books_written')
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='books_published')
    price = models.DecimalField('Price', decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    description = models.TextField('Description')
    upload_timestamp = models.DateTimeField('Uploading DateTime', auto_now_add=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='book_category')
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to=book_cover_path, null=True,blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('title', 'publisher')
        get_latest_by = '-upload_timestamp'
```

**This is view in views.py**

```
def shop(req):
bookz = Book.objects.order_by('title')
var = {'books': bookz, 'range': 10}
return render(req, 'bookrepo/shop.html', context=var)
```

**This is media setting in settings.py**

```
 MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
 MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**This is my folder structure i did put covers in media/covers/publisher/image.jpg EVEN i tried something like this media/media/covers/publisher/image.jpg**

[This is structure of media directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkyKc.png)

**I am getting NOT FOUND error in django console**

[Not found error like these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7TJt.png)

#### I think this have to do something with url i m trying to create must be missing something.

#### Otherwise b.title is working fine. Issue is just with image retrieval.

#### IF anyone don't understand book_cover_path function they can just tell me the way to make url as if books are lying in media/covers/image.jpg because i am unable to do this ALSO. As,

```
cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='covers', null=True,blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this line

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

             to

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media/')
```

because it is the Absolute path to the directory that will hold the file.

and replace

```
<img src={{MEDIA_URL}}{{b.cover.url}} alt="book-image">

              to
<img src="{{b.cover.url}}" alt="book-image">
```

and add these lines in projects url.py file

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf. urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Praveen, Sir. You are great. Thank you so much. I m so very grateful. You have no idea. It worked like a magic.

Answer (score 0):

try this on shop.html ,Check the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.Storage.url).

```
<img src="{{ b.cover.url }}" alt="book-image">
```

---

Comment: Please explain the code, why it works and how it solves the problem.

Comment: So, as you can see I have to display books as products for users to buy. So, I am grabbing their title and cover to display them on shop.html from database. Everything working fine means everything is accessible from db but not the cover image. May be i am doing something wrong in its url.

Comment: **Shyamkumar** It didn't work. Suggest me some alternate. Thank you.