# Django 3.0: Unable to get username in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

#### I have issue is that in template, I automatically get access of username of Superuser (if that is logged-in) but not username of user based on Buyer (Model). User is getting registered and also can login (I can see it in database). But in template I am unable to get username of user other than superuser. I don't what i am missing here. So i am putting all code of view.py here. Also after user logging he sees bookrepo:home and i am using user logic in header.html (bookrepo:home extends header.html)

**I have model named Buyer in models.py file. And based on this model, two modelForm has made.**

**This is code of model.py**

```
class Buyer(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

# additional attributes
contact = models.CharField('Contact #', max_length=16, unique=True, validators=[
    RegexValidator(
        regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
        message="Phone number (Up to 15 digits) must be entered in the format: '+923001234567'."
    ),
], )
devices = models.CharField('Devices', unique=False, max_length=115, blank=True)
picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=profile_pic_path, null=True,blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return "{} {}".format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)

class Meta:
    get_latest_by = '-user.date_joined'
```

**This is code of modelForms**

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):

password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

class Meta():
    model = User
    fields = ('username',
              'email',
              'password')
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(RegistrationForm, self).clean()
    password = cleaned_data.get("password")
    confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")

    if password != confirm_password:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            "Password and Confirm Password does not match"
        )
class RegistrationFormPlus(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta():
    model = Buyer
    fields = ('contact',)
```

**This is code of header.html (NOT the home.html)**

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
     <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'bookrepo:logout' %}">Logout</a>
     <h2>Welcome {{ user.username }}!</h2>
{% else %}
     <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'bookrepo:user_login' %}">Login</a>
{% endif %}
```

**This is code of views.py**

```
def home(req):
bookz = Book.objects.order_by('title')
var = {'books': bookz, 'range': 10}
return render(req, 'bookrepo/home.html', context=var)

def registration(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':

        reg_form = RegistrationForm(data=request.POST)
        reg_form_plus = RegistrationFormPlus(data=request.POST)

        if reg_form.is_valid() and reg_form_plus.is_valid():
            user = reg_form.save()

            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            user_plus = reg_form_plus.save(commit=False)
            user_plus.user = user
            user_plus.save()

            registered = True
        else:
            print(reg_form.errors, reg_form_plus.errors)
            print("else 2 chala")
    else:
        reg_form = RegistrationForm()
        reg_form_plus = RegistrationFormPlus()

    return render(request, 'bookrepo/signup.html',
                  {'reg_form': reg_form,
                   'reg_form_plus': reg_form_plus,
                   'registered': registered
                   })

@login_required
def special(request):
    return HttpResponse("You are logged in. Nice!")

@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('bookrepo:home'))

def user_login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':

    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('bookrepo:home'))
    else:
        print("Someone tried to login and failed.")
        print("They used username: {} and password: {}".format(username, password))
        return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")
else:
    return render(request, 'bookrepo/login.html', {})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `{{ buyer.user.username }}` in your template to show the username of a user.

Comment: You might be able to get to it through `{{ buyer.user.username }}` or if it is a form, maybe `{{registration_form_plus_instance.instance.user.username }}`

Comment: It didn't work also. And no, its is not a form. It is a template to display header.html (which includes navbar and search panel). This header.html is supposed to extended by all other templates.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to extend your django user framework with a One To One Field . new extended Django Model used to store the extra information that relates to the User Model. {{user.username}} gives the username from session.

use this code to authenticate users don't forgot to import

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,auth

def login(request):

    if request.method == "POST": 
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user=auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            messages.info(request,'invalid user')
            return redirect('login')  
    else:    
        return render(request,"login.html")
```

Comment: It isn't working. Firstly, Local variable 'buyer' is being referenced before assignment. And secondly, AttributeError at / 'str' object has no attribute 'username' (buyername).

Comment: change variable name buyer to buy or any variable name and change in context dictionary {'user':buy.user}

Comment: still getting error. UnboundLocalError at / local variable 'buy' referenced before assignment.

Comment: this problem occured beacause you are not loged in. so add  else condation **else:buy='not loged in' **

Comment: Now, Error: AttributeError at /'str' object has no attribute 'user'. I am getting this error from context dictionary {'user':buyer.buyername}.

Comment: share your code i will figure out what is the problem

Comment: This is all of the relevant code. Last time [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61616197/django-3-0-images-unable-to-display-images-in-template/61622423#61622423), you helped me out. Kindly review my problem all over agian once. I think you've slightly misunderstood the theme of my ques. Thanks

Comment: have you reviewed it again?

Comment: You are trying to extend your django user framework with a One To One Field . new  extended Django Model used to store the extra information that relates to the User Model.  {{user.username}} gives  the username from session.

Comment: Yes, you are right. So what I have to do now to get (authenticate) non-superuser in template ? @Praveen

Comment: go to your admin  and select users which you want non superuser and unchecked the super user status and login with it.

Comment: already tried as soon as they become non-super authentication gets jammed up back. I have many other non-super users too.